# Get Tap Position Relative to Widget

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a Flutter widget to set a temperature, meant to look like a thermostat knob. I've extended CustomPainter to actually draw this on the screen and now I'm trying to set the grab functionality so the user can rotate it.

I can use a GestureDetector widget to get a callback when the user touches the screen, but I need to know where it is relative to the center of the knob. Unfortunately, the position provided by the GestureDetector is in absolute coordinates while the canvas works relative to the origin of the widget. Is there a way I can convert one of these coordinates to the other?

That means I need either:

1) A way to get the tap position relative to the CustomPainter widget

2) A way to get the absolute position of the CustomPainter widget

I am unable to find an API which can provide either of these. Does such an API exist?

Context: https://github.com/dgp1130/thermo/blob/master/lib/widgets/temp_picker.dart

The way it is currently, rotating the thermostat works, but the "center" of the touch is actually about halfway above the real center because of the height of the app bar.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert global coordinates to local coordinates using the [`RenderBox.globalToLocal`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderBox/localToGlobal.html) method. To get the [`RenderBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderBox-class.html), you can call [`findRenderObject`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/findRenderObject.html) on the [`BuildContext`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html).

```
--- a/lib/widgets/temp_picker.dart
+++ b/lib/widgets/temp_picker.dart
@@ -41,7 +41,12 @@ class _TempPickerState extends State<TempPicker> {
     return new Container(
       constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(),
       child: new GestureDetector(
-        onPanUpdate: (details) => setState(() => _tapPos = details.globalPosition),
+        onPanUpdate: (details) {
+          setState(() {
+            RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
+            _tapPos = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
+          });
+        },
         child: new CustomPaint(
           painter: new _TempPainter(
             minValue: widget.minValue,
```

This isn't quite right though, because it could behave unexpectedly when the device rotates and the size of your `TempPicker` widget changes. Instead of storing the local offset in `_tapPos`, I would recommend that you compute and save the results of `getAngleFromPosition` in `onPanUpdate` and pass that angle value to your `_TempPainter` constructor. That way, the angle will remain unchanged when the screen dimensions change, as long as the user isn't currently touching the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the `RenderBox` reference, that looks like it can work. I've been wanting to have `getAngleFromPosition()` computed in the _TempPickerState itself as that make far more sense, but I can't because I need to know the center which is only provided within the `paint()` method. Is there a way to get the center in _TempPickerState as well? My attempts to get one from the `BuildContext` failed because the Widget has not been laid out yet.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the localposition attribute of TapDownDetails as follows :

```
GestureDetector(
  onTapDown: (details) {
       //local position
       print(details.localPosition);
       //global position 
       print(details.globalPosition);
  },
),
```